# Strange broken character in the selection list of CangJie5

Tags: fonts, ibus, chinese

[image]

As seen in the picture above, my character selection list of the Chinese CangJie5 input contains a lot of strange rectangular characters (4 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 ). What's wrong with my setup? Should I install and use some particular font or what?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. Installed ibus-cangjie and ibus-table-cangjie5 packages.

Comment: Is the `fonts-noto-cjk` package installed?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Yes, `fonts-noto-cjk is already the newest version (1:1.004+repack2-1~ubuntu1).`.

Comment: Ok.. Then try to reinstall it: `sudo apt install --reinstall fonts-noto-cjk`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Just tried reinstall that, logged out and back in, but it's still the same.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. Sorry. Let's hope that someone else is able to spot the problem.